# SQL: error implied with join, but I think it's in SELECT statement, thoughts?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, right-join

SELECT customer_id,
       payment,
       SUM(payment)
FROM telemon_payments_data payments
LEFT JOIN telemon_customer_data customer
ON payments.customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY 1
HAVING customer.account_created_on between 2016-01-01 and 2016-01-31

+++++++++++

evidently, my customer_id field is ambigious, because that's the error code.  Thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: you have spaces in table name

Comment: You also need a GROUP BY.

Comment: Thanks, I could've sworn I saw an underscore.  I'll have to look at GROUP BY.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if I should have edited or just started a new question.  the error given now is not with the join but, it's the same basic code, so I wanted to append it to this question, and the site suggested editing.

Comment: for recommended behavior going forward, please advise,  thanks.

Comment: MySQL problem here is that you have one `GROUP BY` but selecting `payment` too.  Most SQLs will not allow that.  MySQL is dumb and picks one for you - check this behaviour is what you want.

Comment: I don't understand.  I can't choose sum on a column that isn't in the GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0):

as Mitch Wheat said, the problem is space in your 2nd table

use `January Cohort` AS January

or [January Cohort] AS January

Comment: !#$E, you're right, I thought I had underscore there!

Comment: Followup: can you JOIN a table to a view?

Comment: yes you can.
just assume that View is a Table.
treat it the same

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguous `customer_id` error is because of the fact that both tables have a `customer_id` field.  You need to tell the query which table to pull the column from (i.e., `select customer.customer_id` or `select payment.customer_id`).